# How to return result in last line by pipe operator?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Can I return `time_stamp` in last line without extracting it in curly brackets?

```
{:ok, time_stamp} = Myapp.Repo.insert(changeset) # |> Map.get time_stamp
time_stamp

# {:ok, %Myapp.TimeStamp{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, active: true...}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Kernel.elem/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2) to get an item from a tuple by index (starting from 0).

```
Myapp.Repo.insert(changeset) |> elem(1)
```

However if your changeset is not valid then this will return the changeset, as an invalid changeset will return `{error, changeset}`

If you could explain a little bit about why you want to do this then we may be able to help further.

Comment: asked just of curiosity, however I'll use `case` when insert, thanks.

Comment: On success of an insert it returns the Database item e.g. {:ok, MyDBItem<>} so you could pipe into a pattern matched function to handle success and error cases - `def myresults({:error, changeset})` and `def myresults({:ok, item})`